# Where am I going wrong in function logic

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, quicksort

I am writing a program to do quicksorting with a median of 3. My quicksort algorithm here:

```
void quickSort(vector<int> & a, int left, int right) {
    if (left + 10 <= right) {
        const int & pivot = median3( a, left, right);

        int i = left, j = right -1;
        for ( ; ; ){
            while(a [++i] < pivot){}
            while(pivot < a[--j]){}
            if(i < j)
                swap(a[i], a[j]);
            else
                break;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[right-1]);

        quickSort(a,left,i-1);
        quickSort(a,i+1,right);
    }
}
```

My generated vectors to be sorted (Only sorting vector[0] though)

```
vector<vector<int> > vectorList;

for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    vector<int> tmp(100*pow(2,j));

    for (unsigned int l = 0; l<tmp.size(); l++)
        tmp[l] = (rand() % 20000);

    vectorList.push_back(tmp);
```

And my call to quicksort from main here:

```
quickSort(vectorList[0], 0, vectorList[0].size()-1);
```

My program currently will print out the random values, but it is having trouble actually sorting the values out. I thought I had everything right algorithm wise, but apparently not. I've been through it multiple times and can't quite figure out where the problem lies. Are the any new sets of eyes that can spot the problem and offer me some advice on how to correct it? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Why are you testing with so much test data?  Just try to sort 4, 5, or 6 numbers and follow the code along with the algorithm.  In addition, sort *known* numbers, not random numbers.  The reason is that you want to start out with a baseline that works correctly, and randomizing the data is not a good way to start out.

Comment: One thing that jumps out is these loops: `while(a [++i] < pivot){}` and `while(pivot < a[--j]){}`. They are empty, and don't do anything. I can't imagine this being intentional.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius , it's the algorithm that was given to use in the book. I thought it looked a little funky as well.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius those loops set the values of `i` and `j`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - the loops are correct, but the initial setting should be i = left-1; and j = right+1;. This means the first preincrement of i sets it to left, and the first predecrement of j sets it to right. The idea is for i and j to meet or cross at the pivot (which may get moved due to the swaps). This is  [hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). The recursive calls should be quicksort(a, left, j), and quicksort(a, j+1, right).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is Hoare partition scheme, and that median3 can handle length of 1 more elements. Changes from original noted in comments. Comments described as "same logic as original" are just cosmetic changes, there's no change in the logic of the code for these lines from the original example above. It's possible that the if(left+10 <= right) and the j = right-1 are the only real errors, but this example follows the typical Hoare partition scheme style.

A working implementation of quicksort can be tricky, since a minor error may only fail for specific patterns which may never get tested.

```
void quickSort(vector<int> & a, int left, int right) {
    if(left >= right)               // left < right (not left+10 <= right)
        return;                     //  else nothing to do so return
    int pivot = median3( a, left, right);
    int i = left-1, j = right+1;    // left-1 (not left), right+1 (not right-1)
    while(1){                       // same logic as original
        while(a[++i] < pivot);      // same logic as original
        while(a[--j] > pivot);      // same logic as original
        if(i >= j)                  // same logic as original
            break;                  // same logic as original
        swap(a[i], a[j]);           // same logic as original
    }
    quickSort(a,left,j);            // use j   (not i-1)
    quickSort(a,j+1,right);         // use j+1 (not i+1)
}
```

example median3

```
int median3(vector<int> & a, int left, int right)
    int i = left, j = (left + right)/2, k = right;
    if (a[k] < a[i])
        swap(a[k], a[i]);
    if (a[j] < a[i])
        swap(a[j], a[i]);
    if (a[k] < a[j])
        swap(a[k], a[j]);
    return(a[j]);
}
```

minimal change to original example to typical Hoare partition scheme style.

```
void quickSort(vector<int> & a, int left, int right) {
    if (left <= right) {                         // not (left+10 <= right)
        int pivot = median3( a, left, right);    // const ... & ??
        int i = left-1, j = right +1;            // left-1, right+1
        for ( ; ; ){
            while(a [++i] < pivot){}
            while(pivot < a[--j]){}
            if(i < j)
                swap(a[i], a[j]);
            else
                break;
        }
        // swap(a[i], a[right-1]);               // deleted this line
        quickSort(a,left,j);                     // j instead of i-1
        quickSort(a,j+1,right);                  // j+1 instead of i+1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed, so we don't have to scroll back and forth comparing the two codes?

Comment: @Barmar - I updated my answer to show the changes in comments. I'll delete this comment later, since it won't be needed after you re-read the answer.